# What to call the eigenvalues that don't correspond to a conserved quantity

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems

Consider your favorite continuous time nicely behaved dynamical system.  If we linearize at an equilibrium and the largest eigenvalue is negative, then it's stable.

Now let's add to that system the equation $\dot{Z}=0$.  Your new system has a conserved quantity ($Z$), and with it comes an eigenvalue of $0$, which means if you increase $Z$, the change doesn't increase or decrease.  For your original system, this new equation isn't important to think about.  Once your initial condition sets $Z$ the remaining dynamics are what we care about.

I want to write a theorem where I refer to the largest eigenvalue other than these conserved quantity eigenvalues.  What should I call them?

For definiteness, consider
$\dot{X} = -X + Y$,  and $\dot{Y} = \mu X+X^2-Y$, with the additional equation $\dot{Z}=0$.  If we study the stability at $0$, a bifurcation will occur as $\mu$ changes, and I want to discuss the eigenvalues not corresponding to the $(0,0,1)$ eigenvector.

Comment: I assume that in your true system, you do not *literally* couple in the equation $\dot{Z}=0$, but rather this would fall out of some change of variables. Anyway, it seems like "largest nonzero eigenvalue" would be fine.

Comment: @ian This runs into problems at the bifurcation value where the eigenvalue I want is 0.  But yes, with appropriate change of variablesI would eventually get rid of the extra equations, but explaining that to the audience would be too much.

Answer (score 0):

You can reformulate the problem by considering a reduced phase space. In your example the full phase space is $M= \{(X,Y,Z)  \in \mathbb{R}^3 \}$. Introduce the reduced phase space $M_{Z=c}= \{(X,Y,Z)  \in \mathbb{R}^3 : Z=c \} $. Observe there is no more motion tangential to your eigenvector $(0,0,1)$ so you do not have to deal with the associated center manifold. This extends straight forwardly to more complicated conserved quantities.